# Did you know Sam was getting married?

Tags: tense, verbs

> Did you know Sam was getting married?

Why is the tense of "get married" a past tense if Sam is getting married in the future?

Comment: It's because the decision to get married had already happened.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the question **Did you know....**. The questioner is asking whether someone was (has been) aware of Sam's impending marriage.

It's equally valid to use **is** or **was** in this context.

A classical example is that of the round world.

He said: "The world is round."

Put that into indirect speech and you can use **is round** or **was round**.

In most cases, the verb choice depends on the situation.

If John says he is going to the library but hasn't yet left, you are likely to say: **John said he is going to the library.**

But if he left half an hour ago, you might say: **John said he was going to the library.**

The same guideline applies to Sam's marriage.

Choose which ever tense you think fits the situation best.